# How do I log out of all my active sessions?

Tags: ssh, users, login

For some reason, I have a few open sessions on an SSH server that I don't know about. I assume they're leftovers from when my pipe broke.

```
$ users
user1 user2 user3 me me me me
```

Is there a way to log me out across all sessions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could try killing off the individual processes that are still running as you, or just purge the system of everything running as you: `pkill -u username`

Comment: This command kind of restarts the remote machine and all the opened programs get closed. We are only interested in closing the multiple connections..

Answer (score 13):

```
loginctl terminate-user <Your User Name>
```

should kill all sessions of your user

Comment: It worked! All SSH sessions are logged out =)

Answer (score -2):

```
# ps -ea | grep username

kill -9 id's
```